# Which is equivalent in Android for iOS selectionChanged() haptic?

Tags: android, haptic-feedback

I was looking for `selectionChanged()` for android.
I found some constants on android but nothing for 'selectionChanged' :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/VibrationEffect

Here is apple doc:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiselectionfeedbackgenerator/2374284-selectionchanged

Which could be the equivalent for android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
performHapticFeedback...
```

This is the native way